# How pass value to Custom renderer?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a custon renderer entry

```
public class EntryPerson: Entry
    {
        public int TestInt { get; private set; }
        public EntryPerson(int TestInt)
        {
            this.TestInt = TestInt;
        }
    }
```

and in xaml in have this

```
<local:EntryPerson >
```

but i want to use so:

```
<local:EntryPerson TextInt="0" >
```

how pass untill to my render?

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following code

```
public class EntryPerson
{
   public int TestInt { get;  set; }

   public EntryPerson()
   {

   }

   public EntryPerson(int test)
   {
      TestInt = test;
   }
}
```

```
 protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if(Control!=null)
        {
            var element = Element as EntryPerson;

            var test = element.TestInt;

            //Element.TextChanged += Element_TextChanged;
        }

    }
```

Comment: is well use <local:EntryPerson TextInt="0" > ?

Comment: Yes , you can have a try .

Comment: can have a constructor?

Comment: other question, i need a palete of colors, to get differents kinds of green  new CGColor(0, 100, 5);

Comment: Create a new thread and post more details (like the screen shot about the effect that you want to implement).